# openmp parallel for loop with two or more reductions

Tags: c++, c, openmp

Hi just wondering if this is the right way to go going about having a regular for loop but with two reductions , is this the right approach below? Would this work with more then two reductions as well. Is there a better way to do this?
also is there any chance to integrate this with an MPI_ALLREDUCE command?

```
heres the psuedo code

      #pragma omp parallel for \
      default(shared) private(i) \
      //todo first  reduction(+:sum)
      //todo second reduction(+:result)

      for loop i < n; i ++; {
        y = fun(x,z,i)
        sum += fun2(y,x)
        result += fun3(y,z)
      }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do reduction by specifying more than one variable separated by a comma, i.e. a list:

`#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) reduction(+:sum,result) ...`

Private thread variables will be created for `sum` and `result` that will be combined using `+` and assigned to the original global variables at the end of the thread block.

Also, variable `y` should be marked private.

See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION

Comment: What if there are different operations to be performed e.g. `+` and `max` ?

Comment: @mightyuhu See my answer

Answer (score 14):

You can simply add another `reduction` clause:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    double sum_i = 0, max_i = -1;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum_i) reduction(max:max_i)
    for (int i=0; i<5000; i++){
        sum_i += i;
        if (i > max_i)
            max_i = i;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum_i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max = " << max_i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

From [OpenMP 4.5 Complete Specifications (Nov 2015)](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf)

> Any number of reduction clauses can be specified on the directive, but
>   a list item can appear only once in the reduction clauses for that
>   directive.

The same works on Visual C++ that uses oMP v2.0: [reduction VC++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/2-7-2-6-reduction?view=vs-2017)

Comment: It doesn't work in GCC 7.1. Any idea how to apply 2 different reductions?

Comment: @Royi maybe it's because of the comma after the first reduction term? I don't recall commas being used to distinguish omp parameters.